# SQL Query not return values

Tags: mysql, sql

Im running a bit of SQL on my php app, its meant to return a value that gets compared to the value that does get returned.

The query is returning two of the 4 values that i need.

I've tried to adapt the query so that it will only return the other two that don't show up at all

here's the query

```
SELECT projects.ProjectProperty1, projects.ProjectProperty2, users.UserProperty1, users.UserProperty2
FROM projects,
     users
WHERE projects.ProjectProperty1 LIKE CONCAT('%', users.UserProperty1, '%')
   OR projects.ProjectProperty2 LIKE CONCAT('%', users.UserProperty2, '%')
```

Returns: https://gyazo.com/a8a2961166de9c22d9bbf858b3d765b8

Projects DB: https://gyazo.com/8088ea417f0d4804489621948b989068

Users DB: https://gyazo.com/e43e58857a21239e827a59d4864d099a

On Website: https://gyazo.com/2dc7da5855506f512e3737809cd48cee

I need to get the values of the two that are missing out of the users db.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Tip of today: Switch to modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax! Easier to write (without errors), easier to read and maintain, and easier to convert to outer join if needed

Comment: Most people here want sample table data and expected result as formatted text, not as images (or links to images.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This to get the matched values in projects and users table:

```
SELECT p.ProjectProperty1, p.ProjectProperty2, u.UserProperty1, u.UserProperty2
FROM projects
Inner Join users u on p.Id= u.Id
WHERE p.ProjectProperty1 LIKE CONCAT('%', u.UserProperty1, '%')
   OR p.ProjectProperty2 LIKE CONCAT('%', u.UserProperty2, '%')
```

Try this to get all values in Users table and only matched values from Projects table:

```
 SELECT p.ProjectProperty1, p.ProjectProperty2, u.UserProperty1, u.UserProperty2
    FROM projects
    Right Join users u on p.Id= u.Id
    WHERE p.ProjectProperty1 LIKE CONCAT('%', u.UserProperty1, '%')
       OR p.ProjectProperty2 LIKE CONCAT('%', u.UserProperty2, '%')
```